# Why does Docker checks any node versions if they already installed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have built my custom frontend image

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Than I run it with docker compose

```
docker compose up frontend-app --build
```

Image running and working as expected.

Than I run it with docker compose without `--build` flag

```
docker compose up frontend-app
```

Image running and working as expected.

But when I disable wi-fi (internet), and run previous command again with `--build` flag, it shows me an error:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14.15.5-alpine3.10                                                                                                0.1s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:14.15.5-alpine3.10:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/node/manifests/14.15.5-alpine3.10": Failed to lookup host: registry-1.docker.io
```

What is the point always check for the node updates if node already dowloaded, and even pulled separatly from docker image?

Next command shows that this image localy already exists:

```
docker pull node:14.15.5-alpine3.10
14.15.5-alpine3.10: Pulling from library/node
b038bcb63e9c: Already exists 
2ad96160a6c4: Already exists 
694a34677dcf: Already exists 
253b9b23d1bc: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:fd87531f9bf187273c77ad3ddd5067110ef983f998fc2ea1b9932950df78bd8c
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:14.15.5-alpine3.10
docker.io/library/node:14.15.5-alpine3.10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using --build you are building again the image, why do you use it if you already have the image?
Use just docker-compose down & docker-compose-up

Comment: Actually I don't need to build it again, but sometimes it needed, for example I will change some stuff in Docker file, eg. COPY additional file or whatever, for craating new image I have to use `--build` option, and than I will have an issue with internet, but no internet required.

Comment: Of course sulution for this issue is convinient for regeons with unstable internet (Ukraine). And only required for development purpose, not for production.